# Jetpack Compose Navigation: Activity overlapping with startscreen

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

i have a problem with the NavigationComponent of Jetpack Compose. I have a MainActivity and three KotlinFliles with Composables, that are: HomeScreen, SecondScreen, ThirdScreen. When i implement NavController and NavHost in the MainActivity and i try to start the application, the content of the mainActivity is on top of the HomeScreen.

i searched a lot on stackoverflow and in the web but couldnt see any answer or that someone else would have this problem. Is it intended?

My Code below, hopefully someone can help me:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        NavigationTestTheme {

            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                val myNavController = rememberNavController()

                NavHost(navController = myNavController, startDestination = "home"){
                    composable("home"){ HomeScreen() }
                    composable("second"){ SecondScreen()}
                    composable("third"){ ThirdScreen()}
                }


                Greeting()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And the repetitive Composobles:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(){

NavigationTestTheme {

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {

        GreetingHome()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have both your `NavHost` and whatever `Greeting` is in the same `Surface`, so both are going to be displayed. If you don't want `Greeting` to overlap with your `NavHost`, why is it there? Maybe it would be helpful to explain the expected flow the user takes when your app starts.

Comment: @ianhanniballake youre right. I didnt see that this could be a problem. Somehow i thought navhost and navcontroller would skip every other content in the surface. Thank you. After deleting Greeting everything works fine now. Issue solved.